# How do you change the UIRefreshControl beginRefresh height?

Tags: xcode, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UIRefreshControl coupled with a UITableView and it works fine except that I need a custom height for when the refresh is triggered. I tried the following:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "showRefreshing", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

func showRefreshing() {

    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -150), animated: true)

}
```

And it does reveal the extra space while refreshing, however there is a jitter while it does this. It isn't smooth at all and I am wondering if I'm missing an easy solution.  I also tried changing the height of the refreshControl but it would still use the defaul offset height. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check my answer→ https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662671/2322075